# Not able to access model from other project

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, model-view-controller

i am facing one problem.
i have divide my project into 4 parts,
as showing in below.
[image]

i am trying to access the model from model project in razor view , it's giving compilation error.
please find below .

[image]

[image]

Comment: The web app has the reference to TytoorCourseBuilderModel.DAL project?

Comment: First, screenshots are great, but all errors and such should be posted as plain text. Basically, anything required to answer question should be plain text. Screenshots should serve only as supporting material.

Comment: thanks for quick replay, references already is their

Comment: i can share you the error messages:

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TytoorCourseBuilderModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: public class _Page_Views_MyCourses_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<IEnumerable<TytoorCourseBuilderModel.BAL.CourseModel>> {

Comment: Source File: C:\Users\Halis\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\6dbb5c43\9c84d8ba\App_Web_index.cshtml.26f5b950._eyvwt9r.0.cs    Line: 31

Comment: try the full namespace starting with the solution name which in your case should be, `TyootrCourseBuilder.TyootrCourseBuilderModel.BAL.CourseModel`

Comment: Check that all projects are compiling to the same .Net version. (Project properties)  I've run into similar issues when introducing new projects to existing solutions where the new solutions were automatically set to a different .Net version. (I.e. 4.5.2 vs. 4.5)  Other things to check would be that the namespace on your BAL class matches what you expect. (I.e. copy & paste issues) and that the class is Public.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming TyootrCourseBuilder is your MVC project:

Navigate to TyootrCourseBuilder project in Solution Explorer -> References -> right click -> Add Reference ... -> Projects -> check TyootrCourseBuilderModel.BAL -> OK